# moving linear layout down

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

im working on a app the has 2 linear Layouts in one xml file. on start one linear-layout is set to invisible. When the user pushes a button the visible linear-layout should slide down 90% of the way and show the  second linearlayout. I wrote the animation file and have it working fine. My problem is that after the animation the view goes back to how it was. How do i move the first linear layout down to show the second linear layout? Any help?

MainActivity file:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements   OnClickListener,AnimationListener{

LinearLayout main,menu;
    Button B;
    Animation slideUp;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       slideUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.main_slide_down);
    main=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.maincontent);
    menu=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainmenu);
    B= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    B.setOnClickListener(this);



    main.setLayoutAnimationListener(this);




}



@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId())
    {
       case R.id.button1:
        // main.setAnimation(slideUp);
        menu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        main.startAnimation(slideUp);


        break;

    }

}
```

}

XML file:

```
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context=".MainActivity" >


<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:id="@+id/mainmenu"
     android:background="#6F26F0"
     android:visibility="invisible" 
     android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

 </LinearLayout>


  <LinearLayout 
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:id="@+id/maincontent"
      android:background="#3BED00"
         android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />



   </LinearLayout>





  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried calling slideup.setFillAfter(true) ?

Answer (score 1):

Let's scrap the animations and use a layout trick instead!

**Here's what you need to do:**

*xml*

• Change root layout to `LinearLayout`

• Add `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` to root, mainmenu & maincontent

---

*android:id="@+id/mainmenu"*

• Change visibility to `android:visibility="gone"`

• Change height to `android:layout_height="0dp"`

• Add weight of `android:layout_weight="1"`

---

*android:id="@+id/maincontent"*

• Change height to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

**Now what?**

You're done! Just change the visiblity of mainmenu to visible on the click of your button!

Comment: Great solution!  Is it possible to hook into the animation events when doing it this way.  IE can I tell when the animation is done?

Comment: @lostintranslation I'm not sure about that. You could look into a listener perhaps that would detect start/end positions.

Answer (score 0):

> How do i move the first linear layout down to show the second linear
>   layout?

So here you go:

```
            main.startAnimation(slideUp);
            slideUp.setFillAfter(true);
            slideUp.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

               // Make Your 1st Linearlayout Invisible/Gone &
               // Make your 2nd Linearlayout Visible here.

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to set the layout weight property correctly for it to take up 90% space (0.9 layout weight). Visibility can be toggled between Visible and Gone.