# Slide up/down layout on click

Tags: android, android-animation

I am looking to slide/up down a nested layout on its parent layout click.

Ie the parent layout will have a hidden child.  On click I would like the parents height to animate down (slide down) to fit the child layout.  On click again I would like the child to animate up (slide up).  Basically just animating the parents height to show/hide the child.

I have found this which looks to work but seems like a lot of code:

http://gmariotti.blogspot.com/2013/09/expand-and-collapse-animation.html

I have seen a lot of things using 'animateLayoutChanges' to animate things however I cannot get that to work.

I have tried this:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/child"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Some text to show/hide"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then in code:

```
    LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.parent);
    parent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           LinearLayout child = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.child);
           child.setVisibility(child.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

That sets the visibility of the child view correctly but there is absolutely no animation.

Comment: So is `parent` a `LinearLayout` or a `TextView`?

Comment: See update, sorry :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first of all `android:animateLayoutChanges` effects the child elements. So, obviously, if you are changing the properties of the element itself, it will not be animated.

I think you can accomplish what you are trying to in API 16 by enabling the `LayoutTransition.CHANGING` animation.

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Some text to show/hide"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

---

```
LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.parent);
parent.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);

View text = findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        View message = findViewById(R.id.message);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = message.getLayoutParams();

        params.height = params.height == 0 ? ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT : 0;

        message.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
});
```

Comment: I did have 'animateLayoutChanges' on the parent, but I moved it since I was not having success.  I guess the key is 'parent.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);'  I had thought the docs mentioned a default animation and thought I could just update the XML and see some sort of animation.  I guess that is not true.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have also seen some stuff with messing with 'weight' to get the proper effect without adding 'parent.getLayoutTransition().enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);' in code.  I'll see if I can get that to work as well.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I did also find another way here that works great with minimal code.  Use height="0dp" and weight="1" for sliding content and then only code you need is setting content to VISIBLE/GONE.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21635050/moving-linear-layout-down

Comment: Isn't that just the normal behavior that you get with `wrap_content`? What is the point of the `layout_weight`? It doesn't actually slide the content, it slides surrounding content and fades in the content, which is not what you stated you were looking for.

Comment: I guess you are correct, the weight does nothing.  I was originally having problems getting a default animation with just setting android:animateLayoutChanges.  Question really was here is a link to 100 lines of code to animate why can't I just use android:animateLayoutChanges with no code.  But your answer works great as well.

Comment: @tachyonflux this works great until it tries to hide the view back down to height = 0: the content disappears instantly but the container slides down. anyone else have this issue?

Comment: @lostintranslation android:animateLayoutChanges="true" only works for basic transition like item add/remove animation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **`SlidingDrawer`**

use this code

xml layout **sideupdown.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bopen"
            android:layout_width="90sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="open" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btogg"
            android:layout_width="90sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="change" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bclose"
            android:layout_width="90sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="close" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <SlidingDrawer
        android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:content="@+id/content"
        android:handle="@+id/handle" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/handle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Handle" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/chkbok"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="false"
                android:text="On/Off" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </SlidingDrawer>

</FrameLayout>
```

java class **SlideUpDown.java**

```
public class SlideUpDown extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
        OnCheckedChangeListener, OnDrawerOpenListener, OnDrawerCloseListener {
    Button opn, cloz, chng, hndl;
    CheckBox chkbox;
    SlidingDrawer sd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sideupdown);
        refference();
        opn.setOnClickListener(this);
        cloz.setOnClickListener(this);
        chng.setOnClickListener(this);
        chkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        sd.setOnDrawerOpenListener(this);
        sd.setOnDrawerCloseListener(this);

    }

    private void refference() {
        opn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bopen);
        cloz = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bclose);
        chng = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btogg);
        chkbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkbok);
        sd = (SlidingDrawer) findViewById(R.id.slidingDrawer);
        hndl = (Button) findViewById(R.id.handle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.bopen:
            sd.open();
            break;
        case R.id.bclose:
            sd.close();
            break;
        case R.id.btogg:
            sd.toggle();
            break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (chkbox.isChecked()) {
            sd.lock();
            hndl.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            sd.unlock();
            hndl.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onDrawerOpened() {

    }


    @Override
    public void onDrawerClosed() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

    }
}
```

Comment: That class was deprecated in API level 17.

Comment: until they remove it ;)

Answer (score 0):

In one of our applications we hide and show a header and footer. We do this by changing the height and visibility of the view.

It looks something like this

```
        ValueAnimator va;

        if (show)
            va = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, px);
        else
            va = ValueAnimator.ofInt(px, 0);

        va.setDuration(400);
        va.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(2));


        va.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {

                Integer value = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                topicNavBar.getLayoutParams().height = value;

                topicNavBar.requestLayout();

                if (value == 0) {
                    if (show)
                        topicNavBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    else
                        topicNavBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                if (show && value == px) {
                    animationInProgress = false;
                }

                if (!show && value == 0) {
                    animationInProgress = false;
                }

            }
        });


        va.start();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Missing code to calc height.  Does help some, but do you have to write custom code or can you use animateLayoutChanges in the xml?

Comment: We use a fixed height and calculate DP like this : final int px = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, height, resources.getDisplayMetrics());

Comment: Have not tried it directly from the xml. This code is launched from a scroll listener that monitors how far a scroll area has moved up or down.